# C++ map definition basics

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a problem that I can't resolve. Let's say I have this map definition:

```
map<string, int16_t> Registers;
```

but sometimes, I need to store an unsigned int16_t instead of a signed int16_t.
How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try using `uint16_t` as a second template type for the container you're going to store unsigned ints into?

Comment: Hi Alexander, I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @Alexander: What exactly do you mean? Maybe give a declaration example?

Comment: `map<string, uint16_t > Registers;`. For heterogenous objects (`int` & `uint`), you have to wrap the types in some custom class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use a bigger <strike>fish</strike> type, like `int32_t`, or use a `boost::variant`.

An `int32_t` can store all the values that an `int16_t` or an `uint16_t` can, and it preserves the difference between, for example, 32768 and -32768 (assuming two's complement). If you used some casting scheme with `int16_t` and `uint16_t` the difference between these would be lost as both would be stored as 0x8000. Telling values like 0x8000 apart would require out-of-band information, which if you have, you did not mention.

However, `int32_t` won't preserve the difference between 32767 signed and 32767 unsigned. If that matters, then `boost::variant` can preserve that information.

Comment: Hi, well, let's say I have this:

    map<string, int32_t> Registers;

then if I store a 16 bit value that was supposed to be unsigned then what's the benefit?
I mean, if I have int16_t then if I know that the value is unsigned I just cast it? no? I don't see the point of using a 32 bit int

Comment: @Kam - All 16-bit values, signed or unsigned, will fit in an `int32_t`.

Comment: yes but al 16bit values signed or unsigned will fit in int16_t also

Comment: @Kam but there will no noticeable difference from 32768 and -32768 (assuming two's complement), because both will be stored as 0x8000. Distinguishing them requires out-of-band knowledge, which, if you have, you did not mention.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to use a type that can store instances of one of the types you want to store.

Several methods exist, e.g. variants.

One possibility is:

```
class Foo {
public:
    enum class Type : char { Int16, Uint16 };

    static Foo Int16 (int v)           { Foo ret{Type::Int16};  ret.int16_ = v; return ret;}
    static Foo Uint16 (unsigned int v) { Foo ret{Type::Uint16}; ret.uint16_ = v; return ret;}

    int16_t  as_int16()  const { assert_(Type::Int16); return int16_;  }
    uint16_t as_uint16() const { assert_(Type::Uint16); return uint16_; }

    Type type() const { return type_; }

private:
    Foo (Type type) : type_(type) {}
    void assert_(Type t) const { if (t != type_) throw "meh"; }

    union { int16_t int16_; uint16_t uint16_; };
    Type type_;
};
```

Example:

```
int main () {
    Foo f = Foo::Int16(4);
    std::cout << f.as_int16() << '\n'; // okay
    //std::cout << f.as_uint16() << '\n'; // exception

    Foo g = Foo::Uint16(4);
    std::cout << f.as_uint16() << '\n'; // okay
    //std::cout << f.as_int16() << '\n'; // exception

    // Switch on its type:
    switch (g.type())
    {
    Foo::Type::Int16: std::cout << g.as_int() << '\n'; break;
    Foo::Type::Uint16: std::cout << g.as_uint() << '\n'; break;
    }
}
```

This is basically a `union` that will throw an exception when you try to read `int` but really stored `unsigned int`; Kinda `union` that was made hard-to-use-wrong.

`boost::variant` would be another option.

A third variant, as already mentioned by R. Martinho Fernandes, would be to use a bigger, signed int. It depends on your use-case whether mistyping can be relevant, if you want to allow to store T and then read as U, if you like visitors, if you need to track the type at all, et cetera.

My save, tracked solution is 4 bytes big on my system (because of alignment), as is a bigger signed integer. I think because you store your values in a container, it won't be possible to miss out the type tracking while staying 2 bytes, so I guess your minimum is 4 bytes in any case.

Comment: phresnel, I am such a newbi, I will try to understand what you just wrote and get back to you.
Thank  you

Comment: I think this may defeat the asker's intent to store a 16 bit number. If re-worked to use the 16 bit types, this would be the size of an int+2 on most pc platforms, because many enums are stored in an int. Using an 4 byte signed type (int/long in most places) would be better in many ways. If you used a bool to store whether or not this is signed and re-worked it to use 16bit types you could get it down to 3 bytes per instance.

Comment: @Sqeaky: But because of alignment it would go up to 4 again. I will use C++11's new explicit enum typing.

Answer (score 0):

Either you introduce 1 level of indirection ( losing the entire point of storing int16_t pretty much ), or you need to 2 different maps. Unless you're targeting specialized hardware, or really need to conserve space you're better of storing a straight up int. It will be faster and less hassle overall.

Answer (score 0):

Given the two types are the same size, you can cast the unsigned int as and int. Just make sure you keep track of weather your value is signed or unsigned, which may mean it might be better to use a bigger type so you don't have to keep track of signing.